# getting value of a searchfield and then displaying the matching results sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I added search icon to my tab panel which has navigationview containing searchfield in the tool bar docked top. My question is I want to getvalue from the searchfield and send it store to find the match..if there is any match I want those items to be displayed in the list below the searchfield tool bar. I did lot of search but I cant find any relevant example that helps me. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Here is my view ..

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    docked: 'top',
    style: 'background:darkgray',
    items: [{
            xtype: 'searchfield',
            placeHolder: 'Search... '
    }, {
            xtype: 'button',
            iconCls: 'search',
            iconMask: true,
            ui: 'confirm',
            action: 'search-app'


    }]
 }, {//here I want to show my filtered data 
    xtype: 'list',
    itemId: 'searchlist',
    store: 'SearchItemStore',
    onItemDisclosure: true,
    emptyText: 'No data found!',
    itemTpl: '{Name}'
 }]
```

In my controller I am calling the button and adding the function like this:

```
mySearchFunction: function(element , e, eOpts) { 
    var searchPattern = this.getSearchFieldAction().getValue(); 
    var store = Ext.getStore('ProductStore');
    // here I want to set the param that has to send to the store proxy..I am really not sure how this works 
    store.find(fieldName, value, [startIndex], [anyMatch], [caseSensitive], [exactMatch] ); 
}
```

Comment: Are you using MVC?  If so, how are you controlling what happens when the Search button is tapped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `store.filter()` method.

```
store.filter('fieldToSearch', searchPattern);
```

See the docs here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter

Another alternative is `store.filterBy()`, which takes a function as an argument.  If the function returns `true`, that record is included in the filtered store.
Docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy

Comment: Thank you ..it is working but list is loading all the data and then it is searching in that list .. I dont want the list to show any data before search,when we are give the value then it should show the filtered data .. do you have any idea about this??

Comment: When are you loading your store?  Is there an `autoLoad` on the store?

Comment: I am not using the button ..I am using searchfield keyup so that with every letter it starts filtering .. so first time it is working fine but second time when we start entering letters it is showing all data store = this.getSearchList().getStore(); this is what I am using in controller
  store.load();
  store.filter('DESCRIPTION', filterPattern);

Comment: Stores load asynchronously, so running `store.load(); store.filter(...)` is not going to work.  `filter` will need to be in the callback of the store: `store.load(function() { store.filter(...); });`